# Visual Glitch after full screen games

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gaming

After closing some games in full-screen mode, I find these glitches in the screen.

Examples of games that can cause this :

Minecraft Java Edition,

ProgressBar95.

The glitch is affected by mouse events (move or click) and is affected by windows 10 transparency effects.
It mostly effects menus and tooltips.

I usually fix it by logging in and out or restarting.
It sometimes gets fixed automatically when opening calculator (likely because calculator is full of transparent effects).
when it gets fixed automatically the screen goes black for a second.

### Driver information :

Display adapters : ATI Radeon 3100 Graphics.

Monitors : Generic Non-PnP Monitor.

### Screenshots :

[Start menu items are hidden for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bl6M.jpg)

[Tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGUU.png)

[Menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUJjZ.png)

Please note that I removed sensitive information from the images.

Comment: I assume you have a ATI driver that specifically supports Windows 10 and are running the current version of Windows 10 and likewise have the current (or last supported) ATI driver for your GPU installed?

Comment: I checked for driver updates on Windows device manger and it said it's all up to date.

Comment: That is not an effective way to display ATI display drivers, you need to go to the ATI website, and download the current version.  **You can't even install drivers from Device Manager on the current version of Windows 10.**  Microsoft moved that functionality to Windows Update in 2020.